# Foreach con php poo en mvc

Tags: php, mvc, poo, foreach

¿Como realizo un ciclo en la **vista** después de realizar una consulta **SELECT** en el modelo?

```
public function vistaProductosModel($tabla){
  $vistaInventarioModel = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

   $vistaInventarioModel->execute();

   return $vistaInventarioModel->fetchAll();


}
```

Quiero mostrar todos los resultados de la consulta en la vista

Comment: Quiero mostrar todos los resultados de la consulta en la vista, la única forma que me ha servido: 

 <?php foreach (Productos::vistaProductosModel('categorias') as $key => $item): ?>

Pero va directamente al model y no pasa por el controlador

Comment: Si por ejemplo el fragmento de código que muestras esta en tu controlador, deberías enviar a la vista la variable `$vistaInventarioModel` de modo que en tu vista con ayuda de un bucle la recorras y puedas imprimir los resultados, no es como tal una respuesta pero con esto puedo ayudar al momento